# Which of poll() and multi-thread with blocking recv() uses less resources?

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, c++11

I am trying to build a simple web server with just c++11 and those socket libraries.

I think there are two options for me: `poll()` and multi-thread with blocking `recv()`.(Let me know if you know other options)

1. `poll()` can be just single thread. But the while loop can be quite messy. But you won't encounter a lot of thread-related problem.
2. So I tried multi-thread with blocking `recv()` and set `recvtimeo`. It looks not bad. But I am just curious will this method cost more resources?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Yes, using blocking `recv()` will cost more resources as you have to create more threads to service clients, but it will make coding each thread simpler.  Polling may be uglier, but it uses fewer threads.  Also there is `epoll()`, which is an event-driver version of `poll()`.

Comment: Single threaded with *epoll* is what you really want.

Comment: Second (third?) `epoll`, if it's available on your OS. Otherwise `select` or Overlapped IO, whichever your system supports.

Comment: @selbie actually, multithreaded epoll is what he wants.

Comment: @DavidHaim - No, he just thinks he does.  :)

Comment: Thank you everybody! I learnt about c socket on my own by reading some online articles. I noticed that all articles on this topic are mostly at least 3, 4 years old. A lot of them were dated prior to 2010. Is this topic obsolete? Who people use c socket when there are  python, nodejs, go and etc. What is the need for c socket in 2016 and later?